# Selecting a digital certificate with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm a beginner in the programming world, but I've been enjoying working on automation projects, primarily for my job. However, in many of these automations, I need to use digital certificates to access sites that require this type of validation. I encountered a problem the first time I did this, as I couldn't directly select the certificate. So, I found a workaround by using PyAutoGUI to press 'Enter,' which would select the first certificate in the list and continue the automation. However, some websites encounter issues at this stage and don't allow PyAutoGUI to press the 'Enter' key on the keyboard.

```
# Configure Chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {
    "download.prompt_for_download": True,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
}

chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')

# Initialize the browser with configured options
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

# Click on gov.br
browser.get("https://cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br/autenticacao/Login")
time.sleep(2)

# Click on gov.br
browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="login-dados-certificado"]/p[2]/input').click()
time.sleep(2)

# Select certificate
browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="cert-digital"]/button').click()
time.sleep(2)

# Press Enter
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
```

I attempted to grant administrator privileges in Chrome's settings, but it didn't resolve the issue. The code is still stuck at the digital certificate selection step.